# PHP compare date in mysql to sendmail

Tags: php, sendmail

I am fairly new to php and mysql but I have created a small site that users log into and create tasks to be sent to specified email on certain days

The days are stored in the database as mon tue wed, etc.

The script is will send the information to all the emails in the database when the script is manually.

Using cron jobs I will schedule the script to run two times a day to send out each users data to their emails.

but I dont know how to tell the script to compare the days the users have specified in the database with the current day to see if it needs to send the email to the users email that day

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the days your users enter as integers...

Then use a query like this...

select from `mailinglist` where `daytosend` = dayofweek(now())

FYI.. dayofweek() returns an integer from 1-7

Comment: ok thank you very much for the response, after adding this to the script what command would I need to tell sendmail to send on the correct days after it has selected the days from the database?..sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using integers to map the days, as ChrisG says.

But you could also use the date() function with the string "D".
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Then compare the current day with whatever the user has in the database.